# Yum update on LAMP

Tags: php, lamp, yum, update

When I do a `yum check-update` on my server I get packages like php which I haven't dared to update.

I'm wondering whether it would be safe to update these on my production server (I do have a backup though).

I'm pretty sure my PHP code will keep on functioning on the PHP version to which it will be updated.

But I do worry a bit about the different PHP extension / modules.

Will they still be working when updating PHP?

I'm sure someone has experience with this.

Versions:

- CentOS `5.6`
- Current PHP version: `PHP 5.3.6`
- UPdate PHP version: `PHP 5.3.8`

Comment: How far back is your PHP version?

The biggest changes you'll deal with are deprecated functions and settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With out all the information, I am going to go out on a limb and say that the upgrade is safe.

You did not say what OS you are actually using. If it is something like RHEL or Scientific Linux or CentOS the upgrade will pretty much just work. However if it is something like slack or fedora you have a greater risk.

If you want to make sure, perhaps the easiest thing to do is to fire up a virtual machine and update to the latest and greatest and do some basic testing. There are all kinds of free virtual machines out the like KVM and VirtualBox.

Comment: Updated question with versions

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem you may encounter (without knowing your version) is that you may have deprecated functions or settings in use.

There is some scarier stuff that may affect you such as object cloning and class constructor names that may crop up too.

I can't say I'd recommend performing the upgrade on a production box without some more intel on what kind of version jump we're talking about and how much code is involved.

Edit: Since you've posted your versions - You will have very very very little to worry about - if you still have concerns you can see the line item changes [here](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php)

Comment: Please see updated question for versions. As said I'm pretty sure my PHP code itself can be run on the updated version (Famous last words I know :-) ).

Answer (score 1):

Did you install anything from [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/) by hand? Then you could run into problems. Else you will be pretty safe.

Comment: Nopez nothing manually installed from PECL.

Comment: OK. Then the update from 5.3.6 to 5.3.8 should be no problem at all. Unless you used a bug as a feature and this bug got resolved in 5.3.7 or 5.3.8. :) I did this update already several times and we have many different open source software on the servers and never had a problem.